# GraphQL Sent Proper Data but Variable is Undefined

Tags: node.js, graphql

Hopefully I'm not overlooking something stupid here, but here's the problem.

I'm fetching this Smartsheet data using promise:

```
var getWorkspaces = async function(args) {
  var smartsheet = client.createClient({ accessToken: "key" });

  await smartsheet.workspaces.listWorkspaces()
    .then(async function(workspaceList) {
      var data = await workspaceList.data;
      console.log("returning");
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

and this is my `resolvers`:

```
var resolvers = {
  Query: {
    workspaces: async () => {
      var workspaceData = await getWorkspaces();
      console.log("sending");
      console.log(workspaceData);
      return workspaceData;
    }
  }
};
```

Why is this the console output:

```
returning
[
  {
    id: 000,
    name: 'nname',
    accessLevel: 'ADMIN',
    permalink: 'link'
  },
  {
    id: 000,
    name: 'name',
    accessLevel: 'ADMIN',
    permalink: 'link'
  },
  {
    id: 000,
    name: 'name',
    accessLevel: 'ADMIN',
    permalink: 'link'
  }
]
sending
undefined
```

And more specifically, why is `workspaceList` undefined? I've been at this for hours and cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that your `return workspaceData` is within a callback function of `.then()`, so you're returning in the callback, not in the `getWorkspaces()` function. When you say `.next()`, the request happens **asynchronously**.  When you use `await`, the current thread waits for the response and executes it without needing a callback–– a synchronous call. `await` implicitly calls `.next()`, and adding `try`/`catch` is equivalent to `.catch()`.

```
var getWorkspaces = async function(args) {
  try {
    var smartsheet = client.createClient({ accessToken: "key" });

    var workspaceList = await smartsheet.workspaces.listWorkspaces();
    var data = workspaceList.data;
    console.log("returning");
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```